# Java Eclipse game - restart game

Tags: java, eclipse

I have made a game in Eclipse neon with the language Java, but I was wondering how I can make the game so that if the user presses r he or she could go back to the first screen where it says press spacebar to start. here are my 3 files of code if you need it to figure out the solution.

```
//This is the game file (main)

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Game extends PApplet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PApplet.main("Game");
    }

    James james1;
    Wall wall1;
    Wall wall2;
    Wall wall3;
    public void settings() {
        size(500, 700);
    }

    public void setup() {
        frameRate(40);
        james1 = new James(this, 250, 650, 50);
        wall1 = new Wall(this, 0);
        wall2 = new Wall(this, 250);
        wall3 = new Wall(this, -250);
    }

    public void draw() {
        if(key == ' ') {
        clear();
        background(0, 255, 255);

        boolean loser = wall1.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY()) || wall2.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY()) ||wall3.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY());
        james1.show();
        move();
        if (!loser){
            wall1.update();
            wall2.update();
            wall3.update();
        }
        else {
            reset();
        }
        wall1.display();
        wall2.display();
        wall3.display();
        }
        else {
            background(255, 0, 255);
            textSize(45);
            text("Press Space to Start!", 50, 350);
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        clear();
        frameRate(0);
        textSize(40);
        text("You Lose, R to restart", 25, 550);
    }

    public void restart() {

    }

    public void move() {

        james1.setX(mouseX);

        if (mouseX <= 25) {
            james1.setX(25);
        }
        else if (mouseX >= 475) {
            james1.setX(475);
        }


    }



}


//This is the character file (James)

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class James {

    PApplet p;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float size;


    public James(PApplet np, float nx, float ny, float nsize) {
        p = np;
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        size = nsize;
    }

    public void show() {
        p.fill(255,20,147);
        p.ellipse(x, y, size, size);
        p.fill(128,128,0);
        p.ellipse(x - 10, y - 10, size - 30, size - 30);
        p.ellipse(x + 10, y - 10, size -30, size - 30);
    }


    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float getSize() {
        return size;
    }



    public void setX(float gx) {
        x = gx;
    }

    public void setY(float gy) {
        y = gy;
    }

    public void setSize(float gSize) {
        size = gSize;
    }


}


//This is obstacle class file (walls)

import processing.core.PApplet;
public class Wall {

    PApplet p;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float w;
    private float xw;
    private float yw;
    private float h;
    private float wh;
    private float xspeed;
    private float yspeed;
    public Wall (PApplet np, float ny) {
        p = np;
        x = 0;
        y = ny;
        wh = 0;
        xw = p.random(0, 450);
        yw = p.random(0, 450);
        w = p.random(0, 450);
        h = 30;
        yspeed = 10;
    }

    public void display() {

        p.rect(0, y, w, h);
        p.rect(w + 100, y, 500-(w+100), h);


    }

    public void update() {
        if(y > p.height) {
            y = 0;

            w = p.random(0,450);
            xw = p.random(0, 450);
            yw = p.random(0, 450);
        }
        y = yspeed + y;
    }   

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float getW() {
        return w;
    }

    public float getXW() {
        return xw;
    }

    public float getYW() {
        return yw;
    }

    public float getWH() {
        return wh;
    }

    public float getH() {
        return h;
    }
    public float getxSpeed() {
        return xspeed;
    }

    public float getySpeed() {
        return yspeed;
    }
    public void setX(float gx) {
        x = gx;
    }

    public void setYW(float gyw) {
        yw = gyw;
    }

    public void setW(float gw) {
        w = gw;
    }

    public void setY(float gy) {
        y = gy;
    }

    public void setH(float gh) {
        h = gh;
    }

    public void setxSpeed(float gxSpeed) {
        xspeed = gxSpeed;
    }

    public void setySpeed(float gySpeed) {
        yspeed = gySpeed;
    }

    public boolean col(float ballX, float ballY) {
        if (y + h >= ballY - 25 && y <= ballY + 25 ) {
            if(ballX - 25 <= w || ballX+25 >= w+100) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Hope that wasn't too long for just one goal ;)

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320658/4957418

Comment: i read the article. But are you saying that I should stop asking questions on stackoverflow which means stop using it?

Comment: Actually, I don't mind if you keep using it. The sad problem is that stackoverflow (SO) are **legally obliged** to delete any accounts of people who they know to be of a certain age. If such people would keep their age to themselves, however, SO would have no way of knowing...

Comment: oh i see I had no idea. Well i have my parents agreement and their guidance (I'M TALKIN TO YOU SO PEOPLE). thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything from method setup to method restart and then call restart from method setup.

You get something like this:

```
public void setup()
{
    restart();
}

public void restart()
{
    frameRate(40);
    james1 = new James(this, 250, 650, 50);
    wall1 = new Wall(this, 0);
    wall2 = new Wall(this, 250);
    wall3 = new Wall(this, -250);
}
```

Now just call restart whenever you want the game to restart. In your example: when the user presses the 'r' button.

In games, it really is a good idea to have a Map class that handles these kind of things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) really helpful

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't seem to work for me I put the restart function in an if statement that said if r is pressed, which was inside the draw function. If that didn't make sense here is my updated code

Comment: import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Game extends PApplet{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  PApplet.main("Game");
 }
 
 James james1;
 Wall wall1;
 Wall wall2;
 Wall wall3;
 public void settings() {
  size(500, 700);
 }
 
 public void setup() {
  frameRate(40);
  james1 = new James(this, 250, 650, 50);
  wall1 = new Wall(this, 0);
  wall2 = new Wall(this, 250);
  wall3 = new Wall(this, -250);
 }
 
 public void draw() {
  
  if (key == 'r') {
   restart();
  }

Comment: if(key == ' ') {
  clear();
  background(0, 255, 255);

  boolean loser = wall1.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY()) || wall2.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY()) ||wall3.col(james1.getX(), james1.getY());  james1.show();
  move();
  if (!loser){
   wall1.update();
   wall2.update();
   wall3.update();
  }
  else {
   reset();
  }

Comment: wall1.display();
  wall2.display();
  wall3.display();
  }
  else {
   background(255, 0, 255);
   textSize(45);
   text("Press Space to Start!", 50, 350);
  }
  
 }

Comment: public void reset() {
  clear();
  frameRate(0);
  textSize(40);
  text("You Lose, R to restart", 25, 550);
 }
 
 public void restart() {
  james1 = new James(this, 250, 650, 50);
  wall1 = new Wall(this, 0);
  wall2 = new Wall(this, 250);
  wall3 = new Wall(this, -250);
 }
 
 public void move() {
  
  james1.setX(mouseX);
  
  if (mouseX <= 25) {
   james1.setX(25);
  }
  else if (mouseX >= 475) {
   james1.setX(475);
  }
  
  
 }
 
 

}

Comment: They are all one but had to divide them. Sorry it's impossible to read

Comment: When the game is over, you set the frameRate to 0. When you want to restart the game, you have to put it back to 40. Check my updated answer above: I moved the frameRate(40) statement inside the restart method.

Comment: Thank You GregaMohorko. It seems to have worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just basically copy setup and paste it with a new method name, or even use that same method to make it so when pressed "r", it just calls that method back again. But just for it to be cleaner and much more readable. you can do this.

```
public void setup() {
    if(key.r) { //of course this key.r will have to be created as a KeyListener.
      restart();
    }
}

public void restart() {
    frameRate(40);
    james1 = new James(this, 250, 650, 50);
    wall1 = new Wall(this, 0);
    wall2 = new Wall(this, 250);
    wall3 = new Wall(this, -250);
}
```

You can either create a new class for the KeyInput or do it in the same class, but it should be a little like this:

```
public boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];
public boolean r;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    f3 = (key == KeyEvent.VK_F3);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
}
```

Have a nice day!
:D